# Python Recursion with Multiple Clocks

Tags: python, loops, recursion, time

I am trying to write a Python program that has multiple labels of the same class, with each showing the time in a different time zone, as declared when creating each new instance.

At the moment `time_string_format` is a global. My thinking is that I can have a different string format for each instance of the class by changing the global before calling the class.

This is the class:

```
class winMain(Frame):
    def __init__(self, app):
        Frame.__init__(self, app)

        # establish the base font in a variable so it can be dynamically changes later
        self.base_font = "Times"
        self.base_font_size = int(38)

        # Create object lblDTG_ associated with variable lblDTG
        self.lblDTG = StringVar()
        lblDTG_ = Label(self, textvariable=self.lblDTG, text='lblDTG Not Set!', font=(self.base_font, self.base_font_size))
        lblDTG_.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.onDoubleLeftClick)
        lblDTG_.bind('<Button-1>', self.onLeftClick)
        lblDTG_.bind('<Button-2>', self.onMiddleClick)
        lblDTG_.bind('<Button-3>', self.onRightClick)
        lblDTG_.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

        # start the clock
        time_format = time_string_format
        self.set_time(time_format)

    def set_time(self, time_format):
        # update the DTG
        self.lblDTG.set(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(time_format).upper())
```

Right now the time is set when the class is created, but then never updated. I could use recursion like the following, but then I will eventually run into stack fault when the recursion depth is exceeded:

```
def set_time(self, time_format):
            # update the DTG
            self.lblDTG.set(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(time_format).upper())
            self.after(1000, self.set_time(time_format)
```

Is there some way to do this using iteration? While the clocks are running I still want to be able to interact with them by changing time zone, string format, etc., via the bindings. I'm afraid that using a 'for' or 'while' loop will freeze the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is an *inadvertant* recursion:

```
def set_time(self, time_format):
            # update the DTG
            self.lblDTG.set(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(time_format).upper())
            self.after(1000, self.set_time(time_format)
```

The last line should be something like:

```
self.after(1000, self.set_time, time_format)
```

The call to `set_time` shouldn't be executed *now* as currently written but rather 1 second *from now*.  This keeps it from being a recursion, and from experiencing stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I'm too used to turtle's `ontimer` that I forget that tkinter `after` has a nicer interface.  I've updated the code.